# Can Django's test client use a specific virtualenv?

Tags: django, virtualenv, fabric

Is it possible to configure an instance of django.test.client.Client to use a specific virtualenv instead of the OS python install? If so, how?

thanks!

Edit:
I'm using django.test.client.Client from a fabric deploy script, not from within Django itself. Fabric is installed in the virtualenv. So I'm doing something like this:

```
from django.test.client import Client
response = Client().get(url_path)
if response.status_code == 200:                                                                             |
    return response.content
else:
    # handle error
    pass
```

Comment: why are you using the django test client from a fabric script? (as opposed to e.g. urllib)?

Answer (score 0):

The test client doesn't know or care at all about virtualenvs or Python versions.

As long as you've activated the virtualenv at the time of running the tests, the version of Python within the virtualenv will be used.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the lack of details. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

The test client will use whatever enviornment Django itself is running in. If you load up a virtualenv with Django installed in it, any management commands will use that Django install.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the lack of details. Please see my edit.

Comment: The same applies. When you import anything from Django, it's going to come from the installed Django within the current context. If that's a virtualenv, then it will be the Django in your virtualenv. Just make sure whatever virtualenv you need is fired up first, and that's what it'll use.

Comment: That's what I'd expect, but it's not what I'm seeing. I'll do some tests on a fresh VM.